# how to get values from a text file and put in an array

Tags: java

I have a text file containing:

```
activity = a
duration = 2
predecessor = none

activity = b
duration = 6
predecessor = a
```

How can I get the values of activity, duration and predecessor, and put into activity[], druartion[] and predecessor[] respectively?

Comment: Have a look at an INI file Reader. There are some around the net for Java.

Comment: @user1226004: as you're finding out, you can't post code in comments because they lose all formatting and are unreadable (unless they're a single short bit of code < 1 full line). Consider editing your original post above and adding your code there, and then a comment here telling us you've done this.

Answer (score 2):

Read through the file using a file reader (buffered file reader).
Invoke a readLine() on the reader and do a modulus of the line number ( use a counter) with 3 to determine the array to which the value should be pushed.

Comment: can you show me some sample on how to do that? thanks in advance

Comment: @user1226004: seriously now. You try first and show us what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an efficient code. But it works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("text.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    List<String> activity = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> duration = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> predecessor = new ArrayList<String>();
    String s;
    String result[];
    while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        result = s.split("=");
        System.out.println(result[0]);
        if(result[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("activity"))
        {
            activity.add(result[1].trim());
        }
        else if(result[0].trim().equals("duration"))
        {
            duration.add(result[1].trim());
        }
        else if(result[0].trim().equals("predecessor"))
        {
            duration.add(result[1].trim());
        }
    }
    printList(activity.iterator());
    printList(duration.iterator());
    printList(predecessor.iterator());
    fr.close();
}
public static void printList(Iterator i)
{
    while(i.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(i.next());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this before the original poster has shown the fruits of his efforts.